# Vuforia using Metal and SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, vuforia, metal

I've been using Vuforia for a while in a Framemarker-based augmented reality app on iOS. I've grown tired of using Kitware's VTK and would like to switch to SceneKit. How do I best draw into the Scene's background using Metal and Vuforia?

My current technique (Objective-C) has involved grabbing out each frame of video from Vuforia:

```
- (void)Vuforia_onUpdate:(Vuforia::State *)state
{
    Vuforia::Frame frame = state->getFrame();

    for (int i = 0; i < frame.getNumImages(); i++) {
        const Vuforia::Image *image = frame.getImage(i);
        if (image->getFormat() == kVuforiaFrameFormat) {
            [self.delegate updateCameraSceneWithBitmap:image->getPixels() size:CGSizeMake(image->getWidth(), image->getHeight()) format:OARCameraImageFormatRGB];
        }
    }

    // I also grab out the frame marker poses and convert the matrices to
    // SceneKit compatible ones.
}
```

Then in Swift-land:

```
// Get image into UIImage and assign to background
scene.background.contents = backgroundImage
```

[image]

This obviously involves copying images around unnecessarily as well as converting the image into a `CGImage` and wrapping that in `UIImage`. Currently, using about 50% of the CPU, high-energy impact, and idling around 180 MB worth of memory.

I've also found [this project](http://qiita.com/akira108/items/a743138fca532ee193fe) that uses an older version of Vuforia and SceneKit, but it doesn't perform very well and it takes over the UIView. What I would really like is a way of adding Vuforia camera draw to occur in an `SCNRenderer` or `SCNView` in such a way as to minimize C++ bleed.

How do I draw the camera data coming from Vuforia using Metal into the SCNScene's background so that I can compartmentalize the C++ code in Objective-C++ and generally work in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Setting the background of the scene with UIImage

One way to handle the problem is to use the same method I used in VTK. Simply pass a UIImage into the scene's background contents. Not optimal from a performance perspective, but it works.

```
func didUpdateCameraImage(image: UIImage?)
{
    if let image = image {
        _scene?.background.contents = image
    }
}
```